# Close link in modal is closing all instances of success message div

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]This might be a silly question, but hopefully has insight. The closemessage class is an "X" which closes the success message on success of a response, however on click it's closing all of those particular $addOrderResultLabel divs Any ideas?  Just want it close one of them on click, not all. Thanks

```
var addOrderReturnR = function(data) {

    if (data['success']) {
        $addOrder.addClass('orderAdded');
        var successText = $l(3271) + " " + data['order']['order_number'] +
            " " + $l(3272) + "." + '<a class="closemessage" href="#"> x</a>';
        $addOrderResultLabel.append('<p>'+successText+'</p>').show();

        resetAddOrderForm({softReset:true});
        $addOrderCreate.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $addOrderResultLabel.addClass('error');
        $addOrderResultLabel.text(data).show();
        resetAddOrderForm({softReset:true});
    }
    $('.closemessage').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $addOrderResultLabel.empty().hide();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try $(this).parent function like below:

```
$('.closemessage').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('p').hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's enough to edit:

```
$('.closemessage').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('p').hide();
  });
```

I hope it works for you!